# Debugging a web scraping script that uses Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a csv file, with some urls. When I try to scrape the url text one by one, there is no problem, but when I run a function trying to scrape all the urls, and store them I data frame, I only got the first paragraph.

What do I need to correct?

```
        def extract_text (row):
        try:
            url = row['url']
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(3)
            page = driver.page_source
            driver.quit()
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
            body = soup.find('div',class_ = 'content-canvas Bgc(#fff) Pos(r)')
            list_of_paragraphs = body.find_all('p')
            for paragraph in list_of_paragraphs:
                return(paragraph.text)
        
        except:
            next
    
    temp['text']=temp.apply(extract_text, axis=1)
    news = temp['text']
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

becase `return` does stop the function, so it stops at the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        results = []
        for paragraph in list_of_paragraphs:
            results.append(paragraph.text)
        return results
```

You're returning the function right away on the first iteration of the for loop, that's why you're only getting the first paragraph.